# Error of "Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'"

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've written the following code with the attempt of retrieving the text that is output and changing an empty `<img>` tax. The page outputs the correct information, a plain text URL, however, the JScript code seems to be ignoring it and not returning anything. (`console.Log` for debugging)

https://jsfiddle.net/retched/78t4kfru/9/

From the JSFiddle:

```js
var url = "https://api.retchedontwitch.com/twitchinfo.php?a=gameimage";

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlHttp.send(null);
  var res = xmlHttp.responseText;

  document.getElementById("gamePic").src = res;

  console.log(res)
}

loadXMLDoc();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="gamePic">
```

Is there any particular way I'm supposed to set up my server in order to accomplish this? Or is this doomed from the start?

Comment: Look in the browser **developer** tools console - you'll see there's a CORS error - while you can see, in the **developer** tools, the response, your code can not access it due to this CORS issue. Solution: use your own server to make the request

Comment: WOW. One simple line change to the PHP code and it work. Thank you for that.

Comment: Oh!! so you own that server! Well, yes, then it's even easier :p

Comment: Yeah I kind of had to add: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <some domain>");` or if I want to maverick `<some domain>` = `*`. And after that it worked with no problem.